# Load Javascript after AJAX-fetched HTML is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a situation where the HTML part is loaded with AJAX into a DIV with ID="dynamic content" using **main.js** script. This script is situated inside the HEAD part of **main.php** and it goes like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'content.php',
            success: function(output){

                $('#dynamic-content').html(output);
            }       
    });
```

The Javascript file responsible for controlling that content is situated in another JS file named **secondary.js**. This file is placed just before the closing of BODY again inside **main.php**.

main.php Document Structure:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    ....
    <div id="dynamic-content"></div>
    ....
    ....
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/secondary.js"></script> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Sometimes the content of **content.php** is too large, and **secondary.js** file loads before the content is fully loaded. Hence some elements are not targeted and i have problems.

Is there a way for me to delay for 1-2 seconds the execution of secondary.js, just to make sure that the content is fully loaded?

ps: all above files are hosted on the same server

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does secondary.js do - why not put a call to it in the callback for your `$.ajax` call (where you set the dynamic content)?

Comment: The secondary.js targets an element inside content.php and adds a timer inside it.. If for some reason the content.php loads after the secondary.js is loaded then the timer is not there..

Comment: If that's the case then you should definitely not be loading `secondary.js` as you have it in the sample code or you're guaranteed to have issues. My suggestion is basically what SamuelCook is suggesting though - it seems more likely to me that there's something wrong with secondary.js than that his suggestion is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is async behaviour. Whatever secondary.js does, put it inside a function and call it inside the ajax callback. If you do so, you won't even need two JavaScript files.

Don't try to manage this by timeouts or loading order. This will not be failsafe. You cannot know the exact time the browser needs to load your content. For example, what if you are on very slow internet connection? Don't try to predict those things, that's what the callback is for :-)

Your code could look sth like this:

```
function doSthWithLoadedContent() {
    // whatever secondary.js tries to do
}

$.ajax({
        url: 'content.php',
        success: function(output){
            $('#dynamic-content').html(output);
            doSthWithLoadedContent();
        }       
});
```

Comment: This is working! Adding the secondary.js as a function inside main.js and then calling the function withing the success callback! Thanks a lot Philipp!!

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly load the script using `$.getScript` once the output has been applied to the html tag:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'content.php',
    success: function(output){
        $('#dynamic-content').html(output);
        $.getScript('js/secondary.js');
    }       
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: I will apply it more carefully tomorrow but from what i see right now it causes some problems with the elements..

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would actually be to hand a callback to the function that does your `ajax` call. I probably wouldn't put this in html but it demonstrates the method:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script lang="javascript>
      function doWhenLoaded(someCallback)
      {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'content.php',
          success: function(output){
            $('#dynamic-content').html(output);
            someCallback();
          }       
        });
      }

      $(document).ready(function(){
        doWhenLoaded(function(){
          $.getScript('js/secondary.js');
        });
      })

    </script>
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

Instead of using `$.getScript` you could also load in secondary.js with `main.js` and wrap it in a function call (i.e. `doStuff = function() { /* your code here */ }`). Then you could call `doWhenLoaded(doStuff)` in `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add script after ajax call.

```
   $.ajax({
            url: 'url of ajax',
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#instructions').html('<div>' + data + '</div>');
                $.getScript("js/html5lightbox/html5lightbox.js", function() {
                    $('body').find('.html5lightbox').html5lightbox();
                });
            }

        });
```